# (Java) Advise on loops in program

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How do I write a program to read 5 integers from user input and count how many of them are positive?

Here is my code but it doesn't match the sample run.

```
int count = 0;

System.out.print("Enter 5 integers: ");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int integer = sc.nextInt();
  
  if (integer > 0) {
    count++;
  }
}

System.out.println("Count = " + count);
```

[image]

Comment: What doesn’t match? Please share more details. Output of both levels runs seem perfect as per your code.

Comment: @Suman In the sample run, the user is able to enter all 5 integers at one go. But for my code, it requires the user to key in the 5 integers one at a time. Any way to modify this?

Comment: With Scanner, you can separate tokens with any whitespace - so, space or newline.  You may need to declare your Scanner before the loop; you should do that anyway for efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case in your code when u enter the numbers you should enter them with enter separator, example : 1 enter 5 enter ..., if you want to use space separator 1 2 0 15... use my code, I think im not sur creating the scanner inside the loop create a scanner and read one line find the next int then you create another scanner witch not remember the previous line so you cant use space separator.

```
System.out.print("Enter 5 integers: ");
        int count = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          
          int integer = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.println(integer);
          if (integer > 0) {
            count++;
          }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Count = " + count);
```

Comment: Thank you @gabida! Seems like it was just a matter of placing the Scanner outside the for loop. Cheers

Comment: The only material difference in your answer is to declare the Scanner before the loop.  I suspect (but am too lazy to test) that this is the key; that creating a new Scanner each time as per the OP will discard the rest of the unprocessed line, forcing a nee line for each number.

Comment: Thank you very much @J.Backus, appreciate your inputs too and noted on declaring the Scanner outside moving forward

Comment: Don't close the scanner, this will also close `System.in`. As a general rule of thumb, you should only close a stream that you opened.

Answer (score -6):

```
if (integer % 2 == 0){
    count++;
}
```

Here you are :)

Read some fundamentals at start because later you'll have hard

Comment: The question is about checking for a **positive** value.  You've written code to check for an **even** value.

Comment: Using in condition `integer > 0` each natural entered number will be countering

Comment: @J.Backus oop, sorry, my bad

Comment: In the sample run, the user is able to enter all 5 integers at one go. But for my code, it requires the user to key in the 5 integers once at a time. Any way to modify this?

Comment: I've copied that code, tested in my IDE, and that works. So I don't know why you have trouble.

Comment: Why do you think that anything being odd or even matters, since the OP is asking about positive numbers?